# _tkinter.TclError: bitmap "pyimage2" not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to display an icon on a menu bar, so using this [information](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm), I coded this:

```
img = Image.open("help.png") 
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help",menu=helpmenu,bitmap=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img))
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mine.py", line 67, in <module>
    m.menus(root)
  File "mine.py", line 55, in menus
     menubar.add_cascade(label="Help",menu=helpmenu,bitmap=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2699, in add_cascade
    self.add('cascade', cnf or kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2696, in add
    self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "pyimage2" not defined
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: yes i mean png, I just did a typo, but of course in my code there is no typo, it is png

Comment: thank you, I did already

Comment: I think you should use `image=...` instead of `bitmap=...`. Also, just use `img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='...')` and then `image=img`.

Comment: The error message indicates that the code that threw the error is not **exactly** the same as the code you posted (the code you posted says **menu=helpmenu**, but the code quoted in the error just says **helpmenu**.  Please post the code that actually threw the error.

Comment: @fhdrsdg yes, you are very smart, i changed to image and it works ! thank you very much. But then i wonder what is difference between bitmap and image, for my eyes both of them are images

Comment: @Brionius yes, you are right, i edited. In fact, I removed self.menu= because everything is in a class, but i wanted to remove only the keyword self

Comment: I'm actually not enough of an expert in this to properly explain the difference to you, but you could look a bit at [this](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/bitmaps.html) and [this](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/images.html). That might help a bit.

Comment: I'l also write up an actual answer since my comment solved the question, so everyone can see the question is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a `PhotoImage` you should use the `image` attribute, not `bitmap`.
You can also simply open an image file directly using `ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='...')`

So you can use the following code to display your image in the menu:

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="help.png") 
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu, image=img)
```